# Error while switching from one view controller to another

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uitextfield

I have two ViewControllers. One has a TableView and an Add Button which takes us to the second ViewController, which has a textfield and an action button. User is supposed to insert text into the tableview on the second screen which has the text field.

I have made separate swift files for the two view controllers. For the second view, I am importing the class of my first view. However, when I try to tap the add button to go the second view controller, I get an optional wrapping error. This is an error I get: fatal error: ***[unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNsIc.png)***. And in the debug mode, it highlights the following line of code:

```
    tableview.setEditing(true, animated: true)
```

Code for my first view controller which has the tableview:

```
class MainScreen : UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


var items  = ["Apple", "Fish", "Dates", "Cereal", "Ice cream", "Lamb", "Potatoes", "Chicken", "Bread"]


@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    tableview.setEditing(true, animated: true)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let iD = "normal"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(iD, forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None
}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if (sourceIndexPath.row != destinationIndexPath.row){
        let temp = items[sourceIndexPath.row]
        items.removeAtIndex(sourceIndexPath.row)
        items.insert(temp, atIndex: destinationIndexPath.row)

    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

}

Code for my second view controller which has the textfield and a button to insert the text into my array (items)

```
class TextScreen : MainScreen {


    @IBOutlet weak var keyboard: UITextField!

    @IBAction func insert(sender: AnyObject) {

        items.append(keyboard.text!)

    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically   from a nib.
    }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
       super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }
```

}

I don't know what i am doing wrong. i have also attached a screenshot.

Comment: You need to implement the required functions of UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate

Comment: @Roee84 My TableView is already connected to DataSource and Delegate. I did that in Storyboard. What do you mean by this? Can you please explain more? I have also set up cells and everything but the code is not shown here

Comment: It looks like your `tableview` outlet is `nil`.  Did you connect it the Storyboard?

Comment: @vacawama yes. it's connected to both datasource and delegate.  actually, an interesting thing I have noticed is that for my second view controller file, if I say that "class TextScreen : UIViewController," I successfully transition to the second controller. If the parent class however is MainScreen (the first view controller), I get this error. Why is this happening?

Comment: But you don't say that the table view is connected to your `tableView` outlet, and that's what @vacawama means. So the question remains: Is it connected?

Comment: This property `@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!` has to be connected to the tableView as well.  It isn't enough to just connect the delegate and datasource.

Comment: @vacawama yes, this property is also connected otherwise I wouldn't be able to rearrange cells in my tableview. The problem occurs when I write the code for creating class of my second view controller. if i change the parent from UIViewController to MainScreen (which is my first view controller file), I get this error

Comment: @meaning-matters yes, it is. there is something else wrong going on which i can't figure out

Comment: You should reference the tableView from the MainScreen in the Text Screen. The tableView in setEditing is nil because you only referenced it in MainScreen but not in it's subclass.

Comment: @Emptyless can you please tell me how can I do that in code? I have only one week experience in Swift.

Comment: @Emptyless what do you mean by tableView is not referenced in its subclass? By subclass you mean TextScreen? How do I reference it?

Comment: I have provided a code sample below using delegates instead of subclassing

Comment: @Emptyless can you also provide me the subclassing way because I don't understand delegates and protocols. I haven't learned them yet so it's hard to grasp what you did.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve should be handled with a delegate method instead of subclassing your `MainScreen`.

A protocol prescribes a structure to a class. If a function is defined in the protocol. The class implementing the protocol should have that function. This is why if you reference the delegate from MainScreen like delegate = self, the class holding the delegate can fire any function that is prescribed in the protocol. This passes the data in the function from the TextScreen to the function implemented in the MainScreen

You want to append a string to an array, you need a function which sends a string (or handles it). It is etiquette to also include the sender.

Create a protocol:

```
protocol TextScreenDelegate {
    func sendTextToDelegate(sender: TextScreen, text: String)
}
```

Now you should place a delegate in your TextScreen view as a property of that class:

This delegate will create the link between the class that wants to use the data and the class holding the data. When a method from the protocol in TextScreen is executed (delegate.sendTextToDelegate()) it will go towards any views that referenced it, for example the MainScreen in prepareforSegue (see later)

```
var delegate : TextScreenDelegate?
```

Now let MainScreen conform to your newly created protocol, append it like this:

Now we need to make sure that the MainScreen conforms to this protocol. Just like that if you use a UITableView etc you need to add your own protocol. Remember a TableView will not work if you do not use protocol implementations neither will our TextScreen!

```
class MainScreen : UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, TextScreenDelegate
```

It will say it does not conform because you are missing the delegate method created above. Implement this and do what you want to do:

Now that you added the protocol to the MainScreen you should create the function that you defined yourself in the protocol. Every function in there needs to be added to your MainScreen like this:

```
func sendTextToDelegate(sender : TextScreen, text : String) {
    self.items.append(text)
}
```

To be able to let the TextView know that you want to propagate the data to that delegate you need to reference it. Have your `prepareForSegue` look something like this:

This is what we talked about above in creating the link between the TextScreen and the MainScreen. The MainScreen (which implements the protocol TextScreenDelegate) is used for the link (see vc.delegate = self)

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "YourIdentifier" {
        if let vc = segue.destinationViewController as? TextScreen {
            vc.delegate = self
        }
    }
}
```

Al that is left is to call the functions in your TextScreen now! When you execute your action let the delegate know!
Now in your TextScreen you can simply call delegate methods. Using your code:

```
@IBAction func insert(sender: AnyObject) {

    // Always check if exists!
    guard let text = self.keyboard.text
        else {
            print("error - no text in keyboard")
            return
    }
    delegate?.sendTextToDelegate(sender: self, text: text)
}
```

Make sure that the TextScreen is a UIView again and not a subclass of MainScreen:

```
TextScreen : UIView
```

It is a view on it's own ;)

This seems to be a much cleaner approach to handling what you would like to do.

-- EDIT 2 --

There is a dirty way to test the delegate methods. Create an array in the AppDelegate and append to that.

in AppDelegate.swift

```
var items : [String] = ["Apple", "Fish", "Dates", "Cereal", "Ice cream", "Lamb", "Potatoes", "Chicken", "Bread"]
```

Now in your MainScreen.swift

change your items to:

```
var items : [String] = []
```

and in your viewDidLoad()

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
self.items = appDelegate.items
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

and in you TextScreen.swift

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.items.append('your item')
```

This will save them in an array in the AppDelegate. This is however only recommended for testing purposes of your tableView. The proper way is to use Core Data. Which has plenty of examples on google.

Comment: thanks a lot! However, it may sound silly but i haven't read protocols which is why I don't understand most of the code you wrote. Can you please walk me through? Also, if I am understanding correctly, i create the protocol in MainScreen file?  Please help. Also, TextScreen should import from MainScreen, right? not UIViewController?

Comment: and I don't understand the workings and reasons of prepareForSegue in your code. can you please explain?

Comment: I have updated my answer, could you recheck and if you do not understand it let me know! Can be though pill to swallow after 1 week ;)

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH, emptyless! I am going to go through it and play around and will let you know if I don't understand it. thanks so much! bless you! :)

Comment: I understood what you did. Now if i enter  the text in the field, it does get appended to my array. However, if I tap back and go to my MainScreen, my items array is reinitialized and changes are gone. the new array doesn't get displayed at all. instead it resets to its original size

Comment: i also found another way. i said tableview.reloadData() in delegate method. but idk if it's the right fix, is it? it seems to work but does your method also guarantees that if the app is restarted, array will not be reset to its original contents?

Comment: No, you need Core Data for that

Comment: what does Core Data mean and where can I find the method to implement it? Your help is highly appreciated. today, i learned a lot from your delegate methods!! :)

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much! You saved me today! :)

Comment: If this question is completed then you can close it ;)